# $4 \times 3$ matrix, do rows span span $\mathbb{R}^3$ ? do columns span $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $4\times 3$ matrix,
$$A= 
\begin{bmatrix}
3 &-6 &1\\
   2& -4 &2\\
   1 &-2& 1\\
  5& -10& -1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

a) Do the rows of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$?

b) Do the columns of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^4$?

For part b, I have that there are only three columns hence it cannot span $ \mathbb{R}^4$, but i'm not too sure about part a). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What's the rank of $A$?

Answer (score 2):

The columns cannot span $\mathbb{R}^4$ since the minimum number of vectors required to span it is equal to the number of basis element, which is $4$.
For a), notice that the second and third row are linearly dependent. Thus, we need only look at the first, third and fourth row.
But since the determinant of 
$$\begin{bmatrix}3 & -6 & 1 \\ 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 5 & -10 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$ is $0$, these vectors are not linearly independet and so cannot span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1):

The first and second columns are multiples of each other. The second and third rows are also multiples of each other. What does this say about the dimension of the set of all possible linear combinations of the column and row vectors?